# How to create instances of a class from a static method?

Tags: python

Here is my problem. I have created a pretty heavy readonly class making many database calls with a static "factory" method. The goal of this method is to avoid killing the database by looking in a pool of already-created objects if an identical instance of the same object (same type, same init parameters) already exists.

If something was found, the method will just return it. No problem. But if not, how may I create an instance of the object, in a way that works with inheritance?

```
>>> class A(Object):
>>>     @classmethod
>>>     def get_cached_obj(self, some_identifier):
>>>         # Should do something like `return A(idenfier)`, but in a way that works

>>> class B(A):
>>>     pass

>>> A.get_cached_obj('foo') # Should do the same as A('foo')
>>> A().get_cached_obj('foo') # Should do the same as A('foo')
>>> B.get_cached_obj('bar') # Should do the same as B('bar')
>>> B().get_cached_obj('bar') # Should do the same as B('bar')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why so complex?  Why not simply `getInstance(A,'foo')` or `getInstance(b,'bar')`?

Comment: The actual class is a little more complicated than the one in the example. This part was just the one missing, actually :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import weakref

class A(object):
  _get_obj_cache = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
  @classmethod
  def get_obj(cls, identifier):
    cache = cls._get_obj_cache
    obj = cache.get((cls, identifier))
    if obj is None:
      obj = cache[(cls, identifier)] = cls(identifier)
    return obj

class B(A):
  pass
```

Because a `WeakValueDictionary` is used, the objects will remain cached as long as you have any other reference to them, and you can call `SomeClass.get_obj(identifier)` as many times as you like to get that same object.  If I've understood you correctly, it's the `cls(identifier)` which will hit the database and that's what you want to call less frequently (since you know the objects are immutable.)

If you want to keep objects in the cache even if they are no longer referenced elsewhere, then change the `WeakValueDictionary` into a normal dict.

This requires that *identifier* is suitable for a dict key, and if it's a string (as you have in your example code) then it is.

Comment: Tkank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for. You understood me correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

One usual approach is this.

```
class SomeClass( object ):
    # Something that is precious and needs to be pooled.

class SomeClassPool( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.pool= [ SomeClass() ]
    def getInstance( self ):
        if len(self.pool) == 0:
            self.pool.append( SomeClass() )
            # maybe allocate several, depends on the costs
        return self.pool.pop()
    def release( self, anInstance ):
        self.pool.append( anInstance )
```

We separate the pool from the objects being pooled.  They have nothing to do with each other.

You can subclass the objects being pooled all you want.

You can -- independently -- change the pooling strategies without breaking or retesting the objects being pooled.

Comment: Yep, thanks. In fact, what I want to do is not really a common Pool. I don't want to have many classes that do the same thing and take one as needed. I have only one instance for one given init parameter (like an user ID, for example), and I want to return the correct instance each time, without removing it from the pool (the class supports concurrents accesses seamlessly, as it's readonly...)

Comment: "I want to return the correct instance each time, without removing it from the pool".  You mean you want a dictionary of objects?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on S.Lott's comment:

> "I want to return the correct instance
>   each time, without removing it from
>   the pool". You mean you want a
>   dictionary of objects? -S.Lott

```
the_cache = {}

def get_obj(cls, identifier):
    key = (cls, identifier)
    if key not in the_cache:
        the_cache[key] = cls(identifier)
    return the_cache[key]
```

or

```
def get_obj(cls, identifier):
    key = (cls, identifier)
    try:
        return the_cache[key]
    except KeyError:
        the_cache[key] = cls(identifier)
        return the_cache[key]
```